# How to create a metamask address(custodial) for a user who can login with Gmail

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, metamask, dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am trying to implement a dApp in which instead of asking users to create metamask account. I am thinking to create a Metamask address(Custodial) for each user when they login with Gmail and Private keys are stored with us and we can only display them public address. Any suggestions are hugely appreciated

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

You can create a address normally but you need to use the same mnemonic generator that metamask does to decryptography the key.